# How can I use C++ to read a file saved with Java (writeObject)

Tags: java, c++, binary

This is a newbie type of question. I have a file saved using writeObject method in java. I need to read using C++ for a C++ based code. I tried to read using binary file read method while I could not read properly.

```
char buffString[50];

char buffer[100]; 
std::ifstream conFile(configFileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
//conFile.read(buffer, 100);
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
if (!conFile) {
    std::cout << " Error reading thee file " << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Trying to read." << std::endl;
    conFile.seekg(0);
    conFile.read(buffer,14);  strcpy(buffString, buffer);
    std::cout << buffString << "   buffer " << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

The datafile pointed to by this conFile contains string, integer and double. The file contains something like the following:

> trapezDET.pngtcmstMeVsrjava.lang.Double���J)k�Dvaluexrjava.lang.Number���
>                                                                                    ���xp@dsq~@Nsq~@dsq~@V�srjava.lang.Integer⠤���8Ivaluexq~sq~?�sq~  sq~?ə�����sq~       q~sq~@F�sq~?�sq~?�sq~?�sq~?�z�G�{t5/home/vega/NetBeansProjects/Tom/data/6133.root

I searched the net while I could not figure it out.
Thanks and regards

Comment: I guess your best option would be to save the file as plain text. Even with Java alone I would not recommend using default object serialization to store configuration values.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? I mean, the intention is important here.

Comment: save it in some standard format; key/value pairs, yaml, xml, json, anything other than java object serialization

Comment: If you have no control over the generation of the file, I would write a **Java** program to read it and re-save the needed information in something easy to read like *plain text*.

Comment: The JAVA code is developed as GUI which has 3D geometry and 3D graph and prepares configuration file. Then the C++ code uses that configuration and ROOT (CERN) data file to process and simulate the physics. The intention of JAVA based code is that user from different platform may generate their own configuration and then they may run the simulation at server. @Marvin, binary file was generated so that user can not change it after generation. However, as suggested, I have to save in text, it seems.  Thanks everyone for kindly clearing out my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java serialization specification is pretty well defined.  I think this is the latest spec:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html

However it's not going to be terribly easy to create something that reads this file format.  If possible, a more portable output format should be used on the Java end.

(Here's a link to the part that actually talks about the binary specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html )

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do it for simple and fixed classes like `java.lang.String`, but in general the answer is that you can't. In general you will need a JVM to decode such a file. The reason is that any class can define its own Serialization sub-protocol, and only the code in that class knows what that sub-protocol is, and the only way to execute that code is with a JVM.